# Summing a column based on the top the largest values in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

My databases are broken out into teams-games and user-games. Each team can play in multiple games (no limit) that have their own `total_points` column. The team's `total_points` are the sum of the user-games `points` column. It is setup like this:

table: team_games

| team_id | game_id | total_points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 20 |
| 1 | 3 | 30 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |

table: user_games

| user_id | team_id | game_id | points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 13 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 13 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 17 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | 0 |

My goal is to find each users sum of points in their teams top three scoring games. I am having trouble getting the top three scoring games and summing up the users scores for those. I have tried something like below where I limit the rows to 3 to get the top three games but can not get anything to work properly.

```
SELECT
   ...
FROM team_games tg
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
      ug.game_id
      sum(ug.points)
   FROM user_games ug 
) AS scores ON scores.game_id = tg.game_id              
ORDER BY tg.total_points DESC
LIMIT 3
```

My goal would to have the following output for every user on the team:

| user_id | points |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 29 |
| 2 | 31 |

Any ways to pass the top three `game_ids` to `user_games` table to sum the points for each user? I don't want there to be a limit of 3 results on the entire table.

Comment: Thanks for the sample data and your attempt. Ideally you would also include the data you would expect to see for your desired results.

Comment: @Stu sorry! I just added a table of what I was looking for.

Comment: As to your data model: You should not store the game sums in order to avoid redundancy (and possibly data inconsistencies one day). And you store the team with the  user game scores, because a user can switch teams, i.e. play first in one team and later in another, yes?

Comment: With top n tasks there is always the thing about ties. You want to consider the top games a user participated in and then add up the user's score. But what if the top games have the totals 30, 30, 20, 20, and 10 in which the user scored 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5? Only consider two games (score sum 1 + 2 = 3)? Or four (score sum 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10)? Or three, by picking one of the score 20 games arbitrarily (score sum either 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 or 1 + 2 + 4 = 7)? You seem to want the latter. Isn't it a problem that the result is not deterministic then? The results can differ a lot thus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a CTE for this. Would be nice to have more data to see if this works for you. Need to determine your expected results if multiple games have the same top score, such as how to treat if four games are in top three scoring category. Would you want to just add up the four games then? If so, this should work. Also, may want to change the join to LEFT join, depending what you are trying to show.

```
    with top_games as 
    (select team_id, game_id,  
    rank() over (partition by team_id order by total_points desc) as g_rank
    from team_games
     )
    select u.user_id, sum(u.points) as total_points
    from user_games u
    join top_games tg
     on tg.game_id = u.game_id
    where g_rank < 4
    group by u.user_id
```

DB fiddle found here.. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ox6RoGQJTFQYXZgsGZUJKC/0

Answer (score 0):

I find the logic a little hard to follow.  I think you need to order the team scores by the userid and team to select the top three games per user:

```
select user_id, sum(score)
from (select ug.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, team_id order by tg.score desc) as seqnum
      from user_games ug join
           team_games tg
           using (team_id, game_id)
     ) ugt
where seqnum <= 3
group by user_id
```